# sshd active (listening), ssh packets incomming, but sshd not answering

Tags: centos, ssh, linux-networking

1) I'm on Centos 7.X (latest), KVM VM, on www

2) The VM has two interfaces internal (10.0.0.X, `eth0`) and external (176.y.y.y, `ens7`).

3) I've a vanilla `sshd` configuration (that is, it listen on all interfaces/ips)

4) If I ssh on the VM from the www, I can trace (`tcpdump -i ans7 ....`) the incoming ssh packets

5) With `ss -nlput` I get (I delete white space to get the result of the command on a single line)

```
[...]
tcp   LISTEN     0      128    *:22   *:*   users:(("sshd",pid=1494,fd=3))
[...]
```

6) I rebooted, I restarted the services, but `ssh` does not work from www (only from the internal network `10.0.0.1/24`) and with `tcpdump` I see that there are no returning `ssh`-packets.

I have spent more that one hour on a task that I've done 100 times, but I have no idea where to look now.

**EDIT** Also  `ping` does not work, probably it is a network problem.

Comment: Typical things to check: is the interface up and configured correctly (netmask?). Are routes and your default gateway correct and is the traffic not blocked in your firewall?

Comment: Thanks for repl. Interface is up (ip addr + trace in tcpdump); netmask and gateway same as other VMs with dueal interface configuration. But now I noticed a strange thing: in firewalld I have eth0 and eth1 (althought eth1 is not even defined). In any case the ssh problem is with ens7.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was the wrong default route.